# geom_rect, geom_bar, geom_point : how to set line shape for the geom_bar legend only?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some trouble to set a vertical line in a legend for the `geom_bar` independently from `geom_rect` and `geom_point`. It's pretty hard for me because i can't split `geom_bar` and `geom_rect` from the `fill` group to correctly set the color and the alpha.

Here an example of a data set (reproducible):

```
library(reshape2)
s1 <- seq(1,130000)
y1 = (cos(s1)^3)
y2 = (sin(s1)^3)
y3 = (sin(sin(s1)^3))
df1 <- data.frame(s1, y1, y2, y3)
dm1 <- melt(df1, id.var='s1')
xmin <- c(34800,36400,36700,36900,37300,39600)
xmax <- c(36300, 36500, 36700, 37000, 39000, 4000)
ymin <- c(-0.56, -0.60, -0.65, -0.56, -0.60, -0.56)
rect <- data.frame(xmin, xmax, ymin)

library(ggplot2)
#Open a layer with some option
ggplot() + xlim(34800, 42000) + ylim(-1, 1) + xlab("") + ylab("") + 
#plot geom_bar
 geom_bar(data = subset(dm1, variable %in% c("y3")), aes(x=s1, y=value, fill = variable, alpha=variable, group=variable), stat = "identity", position="identity", alpha = 0.5 ) +
#plot geom_point
geom_point(data=dm1[dm1$variable!="y3", ], aes(x = s1, y = value, color = variable, alpha= variable, group=variable )) + 
#plot geom_rect
geom_rect(aes(NULL, NULL, xmin = rect$xmin, xmax = rect$xmax, ymin = rect$ymin, ymax = rect$ymin + 0.05, fill="rect", alpha = "rect"), alpha = 0.5) +
#set alpha for each plot (not include in the legend)  
scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.8, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5), name = element_blank(), guide = 'none') + 
#set colour for fill group
scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "red"), name = "back", labels = c("rect", "y3")) + 
#set colour for color group
scale_color_manual (values = c("green", "blue"), name="Point", labels = c("y1", "y2"))
```

Current output:
[image]

At this stage i want to set a red vertical line for y3 legend only (not a red square).

#### trying set a vline-like shape for y3

```
+  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 'solid', fill=c("black", NA))))
```

Obviously it can't worked because of the link between the `fill` group...

Any idea or proposal ?

Comment: There  may be an error in your code. In the call to `geom_bar(...)` you use a subset of `dm1`, but `dm1` does not have a column `y3`. So in the `aes(...)` argument, ggplot is going to the vector `y3` defined outside of `dm1`. Is that what you intended??

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I have edited my code: `geom_bar(..., aes(x=..., y = value )`. But the output is still the same, just like my question: how to change the red square in the legend, for y3, by a red vertical line ? (concordantly with the shape of the y3 graph, in this output)